# Typo3: creating sideblock using PHP code

Tags: typo3, sidebar, typoscript

I have a piece of PHP code which I would like to integrate into Typo3 as a sideblock for a custom extension I have written.

Can someone tell me how to integrate PHP code into Typo3 as a sideblock or alternatively  point me towards some sample code I can look at. I don't want to use typoscript or anything like that, just plain PHP code but so far I have been unable to find a method of doing so.

Any tips would me much appreciated.

Greetings/Thanks
R

Answer (score 3):

I think you need use typo3 "userfunc". The below link may help you:

http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/common-problems-and-solutions/simple-userfunc.html

Comment: This should work, be aware that if your PHP code produces output based on GET/POST/SESSION variables, you should look into the caching mechanism, esp. the concept of cHash (read at least http://typo3.org/documentation/article/the-mysteries-of-chash). If neccessary, replace USER in the code from typo3wizard with USER_INT, to tell typo3 you'll take hand of caching yourself (read Steffen Kampers "Using Cache in Extensions" at http://buzz.typo3.org/people/steffen-kamper/article/using-cache-in-extensions/). Sloppy coding also includes using USER_INT and not caring about caching at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I'll try this on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider the tscobj extension (http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tscobj), which allows you to include an object like the one created by typo3wizards userfunc-code provided by Sankar V, as a content element in the editing environment of TYPO3. Remember to use "lib." as top-level identifier instead of "temp.", as is done in the snippet for typo3wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Create a small extensions with the [TYPO3 Extension kickstarter](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kickstarter) and insert it as a content element on the "sideblock part" of you website.